# Multidimensional array in php( have same key different values) how can I create a new name for the key?

Tags: php, arrays

I currently have a multidimensional array with two subarrays. The way the database is constructed gives me this result. what I want to do is create a new array with submission id and have the other values merged together. the only problem is that the values are the same keys but not the values.

```
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [sub_field_id] => 123
            [submission_id] => 8
            [field_id] => 81
            [form_id] => 9
            [value] => Male
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [sub_field_id] => 130
            [submission_id] => 8
            [field_id] => 92
            [form_id] => 9
            [value] => N4 Mar 27 theory Apr 20-23 onbike
        )
)
```

I tried using foreach to create a new array

```
    $this_submission = $sub_array['submission_id'];
    $submission_keys[$this_submission][$result] = array('value'=> $sub_array['value']);
  }
```

```
But the results don't help
[8] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [value] => Male
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [value] => N4 Mar 27 theory Apr 20-23 onbike
                )

        )
```

what I would like to get is the following:

```
[8] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [gender] => Male,
                    [date] => N4 Mar 27 theory Apr 20-23 onbike
                )
        )
```

Is this possible?

Comment: `[value] => Male` where do you get the key `gender` to set the key value as `[gender] => Male,` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have all the arrays in a pattern like you show above this code works. working solution [demo](https://tehplayground.com/v0optt0PEu2eKA2F)

```
$arr = [
    [
        "sub_field_id" => "123",
        "submission_id" => "8",
        "field_id" => "81",
        "form_id" => "9",
        "value" => "Male",
    ],
    [
        "sub_field_id" => "123",
        "submission_id" => "8",
        "field_id" => "81",
        "form_id" => "9",
        "value" => "N4 Mar 27 theory Apr 20-23 onbike",
    ]   
];

$res_arr = [];
$arr_count = count($arr);
foreach($arr as $key=>$val){

    if($key < $arr_count-1){

        //here I am getting the last value from the current array and the next array.
        //so if you know the key names you can get the value as $val = $arr[$key]['key_name'];
        $end_val1 = end($arr[$key]);
        $end_val2 = end($arr[$key+1]);

        $temp = array_merge($arr[$key], $arr[$key+1]);
        array_pop($temp);
        array_values($temp);
        $temp['gender'] = $end_val1;
        $temp['date'] = $end_val2;

        $res_arr[] = $temp;
    }
}

print_r($res_arr);
```

Output:

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [sub_field_id] => 123
        [submission_id] => 8
        [field_id] => 81
        [form_id] => 9
        [gender] => Male
        [date] => N4 Mar 27 theory Apr 20-23 onbike
    )

)
```